# How to replace multiple select elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do multiple things at the same time...

1. Replace a select dropdown
2. Have the select dropdown trigger the visibility of a div (it's a child of the div after #1).

I have this HTML:

```js
let $displays = $('.view-id-dashboard');
$displays.eq(1).toggle();
let $selects = $('.dashboard-select');
$('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order"]').each(function(index) {
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text('Edited/Created by me');
  this.replaceWith($selects.get(index));
});
$selects.on('change', function() {
  $selects.val(this.value);
  $displays.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view view-dashboard view-id-dashboard view-display-id-embed_1">
  <p>
    First div, contains lots of things, I only kept the select dropdown to be replaced.
  </p>
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order" id="edit-sort-order" name="sort_order" class="form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
    <option value="ASC">Asc</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Desc</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="view view-dashboard view-id-dashboard view-display-id-embed_2">
  <p>
    Second div, contains lots of things, again only kept the relevant select below.
  </p>

  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order" id="edit-sort-order" name="sort_order" class="form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
    <option value="ASC">Asc</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Desc</option>
  </select>
</div>

<p>
  I added this verbatim and this is the problem.
</p>
<select class="dashboard-select form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
  <option value="edited_by_me">Edited by me</option>
  <option value="created_by_me">Created by me</option>
</select>
<select class="dashboard-select form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
  <option value="edited_by_me">Edited by me</option>
  <option value="created_by_me">Created by me</option>
</select>
```

This works as intended but I am very unhappy I needed to add the same `<select class="dashboard-select` twice. I tried various ways of `.clone()`, `.add()` and such to no avail.

Comment: `this.replaceWith($selects.get(index));` says replace (each) edit box with one *that has the same index* - as you have 2 being replaced, you need 2 to make the replacements.

Comment: As noted in [replaceWith()](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), using a jquery object (or DOM node (this part isn't clear)) will  *replace the target by being moved from its old location, not by being cloned.*.  So maybe `this.replaceWith($selects.clone());` or `this.replaceWith($selects.html());`.  **Edit** either/both should work: https://jsfiddle.net/m264pgvb/

Comment: Yeah, as I noted I tried quite a few variatons with clone() and such and I couldn't get it to work. I expect the solution will contain a `.clone()` call, yes.

Comment: Side note: it is invalid in HTML to have multiple elements with the same `id` atttribute.

Comment: *"couldn't get it to work"* - exactly which part didn't work?  Your code, as provided, with the change to `.clone()` should copy the content ok, but then the `.on("change")` in your code will not work because `$selects` is not a live query, so won't include any new copies.  Either use event delegation or change `$selects.on('change',` to `$('.dashboard-select').on('change',` to reselect the new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adapted version that only has *one* `select` at the end of your document.

The idea is to hide it (serving as a template), and to clone it in the initialisation code.

```js
let $displays = $('.view-id-dashboard');
$displays.eq(1).toggle();
let $selects = $('.dashboard-select').hide(); // There's only one now
$('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order"]').each(function(index) {
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text('Edited/Created by me');
  this.replaceWith($selects.clone(true).show().get(0)); // Clone
});
// Refresh the collection: now there are three (including the template)
$selects = $('.dashboard-select');
$selects.on('change', function() {
  $selects.val(this.value);
  $displays.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view view-dashboard view-id-dashboard view-display-id-embed_1">
  <p>
    First div, contains lots of things, I only kept the select dropdown to be replaced.
  </p>
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order" id="edit-sort-order" name="sort_order" class="form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
    <option value="ASC">Asc</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Desc</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="view view-dashboard view-id-dashboard view-display-id-embed_2">
  <p>
    Second div, contains lots of things, again only kept the relevant select below.
  </p>

  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order" id="edit-sort-order" name="sort_order" class="form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
    <option value="ASC">Asc</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Desc</option>
  </select>
</div>

<p>
  I added this verbatim and this is the problem.
</p>
<select class="dashboard-select form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
  <option value="edited_by_me">Edited by me</option>
  <option value="created_by_me">Created by me</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. What I fundamentally missed is the need to refresh. To avoid writing the selector twice, I used `let selects = () => $('.dashboard-select');` and then `selects().` everywhere like `selects().hide();`. Also, since the event handlers are added later, I believe just clone() is enough, no need for clone(TRUE).  I used just `selects` vs `$selects` because I think $-variables are traditional for jQuery objects.

Comment: The downside of the function `selects()` is that it needs to execute on every change event.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div to hold the moved selects, and use `append()` to move the selects there.

```js
let $displays = $('.view-id-dashboard');
$displays.eq(1).toggle();
let $selects = $('select[data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order"]');
let $container = $('#select-container');
$selects.each(function(index) {
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text('Edited/Created by me');
  $container.append(this);
});

$selects.on('change', function() {
  $selects.val(this.value);
  $displays.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view view-dashboard view-id-dashboard view-display-id-embed_1">
  <p>
    First div, contains lots of things, I only kept the select dropdown to be replaced.
  </p>
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order" id="edit-sort-order" name="sort_order" class="form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
    <option value="ASC">Asc</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Desc</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="view view-dashboard view-id-dashboard view-display-id-embed_2">
  <p>
    Second div, contains lots of things, again only kept the relevant select below.
  </p>

  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-sort-order" id="edit-sort-order" name="sort_order" class="form-select form-element form-element--type-select">
    <option value="ASC">Asc</option>
    <option value="DESC" selected="selected">Desc</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="select-container">
</div>
```

Comment: this does not replace.

Comment: That's because there's nothing to replace -- he didn't want to create all the elements that are being replaced.